# jQuery Select Box Redirections

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I've got a WordPress plugin that works very well for most things I want it to do.  The main thing is that it offers the ability to select the delivery method from the WooCommerce product menu page.  But I've been asked for the available menu options to be filtered by delivery method and I can't see a way of doing this live on the page, so what I've come up with is a "simpler" solution.

I'm intending to set up three different page implementations of the menu, one for each of the delivery options (deliver, pick up and eat in), each with categories filtered via shortcode for that delivery method. When the page loads I've got jQuery setting the default option for the dropdown to match that page and then whenever the dropdown is changed from this option it can trigger a redirect to one of the other relevant pages.

I know this is a messy way of doing it, but I have no idea how to filter the products on the menu any other way. I'm open to improvement suggestions.

Anyway, I've got this partially working.  I can set the dropdown default on page load easily enough, and I've managed to get an if statement kind of working, but it only seems to work for the first option and no others.  I also can briefly see **ifelse undefined** in the console before the page changes on a redirect.  I've also tried to use a variable, but whenever I've tried using it in the if condition checks it just comes up as undefined or null even though I can view it on the previous line like this:

```js
jQuery("#fdoe_delivery_dropdown").on("change",function(){//Getting Value
     var selValue = $("#fdoe_delivery_dropdown").val();
     console.log ("Variable delivery method is - " + selValue);
```

Obviously, I know a variable would be a better way to go, but because I can't get it to work, here's what I've got so far:

```js
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  //Set opening delivery method for "Delivery" page
  jQuery("#fdoe_delivery_dropdown").val("delivery").change();
  //Check initial delivery method
  console.log ("Opening delivery method is - " + jQuery('#fdoe_delivery_dropdown').val());
  
  if($("#fdoe_delivery_dropdown option:selected").val() == "pickup") {
    //Log success to console and redirect
    console.log ("New delivery method is - "  + jQuery('#fdoe_delivery_dropdown').val());
    window.location.replace("{site_url}/pickup/"); }
  elseif($("#fdoe_delivery_dropdown option:selected").val() == "eatin") {
    //Log success to console and redirect
    console.log ("New delivery method is - "  + jQuery('#fdoe_delivery_dropdown').val());
    window.location.replace("{site_url}/eatin/"); }
  });
});  
</script>
```

HTML:

```html
<select id="fdoe_delivery_dropdown" class="form-control input-lg"><option value="pickup" selected="">Pick Up</option><option value="delivery">Delivery</option></select>
```

**Note:** I have used the WordPress variable {site_url} instead of publishing the website on here, I have no idea if this would actually work in jQuery, but I appreciate it would be much better to use a dynamic URL like this rather than a hard-coded one.

As I've said, this script partially works and I've had to put it in a HTML block on the individual pages to get it to trigger at present. How can I get this working?

Comment: Can you share your HTML code as well?

Comment: There's not much to see with the HTML, but I've added it in for you anyway

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to achieve redirect based on the select option. check below code.

```js
$('#fdoe_delivery_dropdown').on('change', function(){
   window.location = 'https://exmaple.com/'+$(this).val();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="fdoe_delivery_dropdown" class="form-control input-lg">
    <option value="pickup" selected="">Pick Up</option>
    <option value="delivery">Delivery</option
</select>
```

Comment: Yep, this basically works perfectly in this instance.  Although as a note to anyone reading this, I have no direct control over the values of the select box as it's part of a plugin made by someone else.  But because I've named the new pages after values it uses this solution works!  Thank you @Bhautik